# Doctrine 2 can't run SELECT query issue

Tags: php, sql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have encountered this issue which I don't know why is happening.
I code with `dao.account.php` like this:

```
$sql = " 
        SELECT last_ip
        FROM accounts 
        WHERE login IN (:strAcc) 
";
$strAcc = " \'acb\' , \'gfh\' ";
$pdo = $this->em->getConnection();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue('strAcc',$strAcc);         
$stmt->execute();               
$rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $rs;
```

But it returns `array(0){}`.
I don't know why??? In my database, the query ran well.
Could someone help me???

Comment: Did you get any error? Can you post it.

Comment: i have no error. That's y i'm scared of it.

Comment: @Samir from the evidence we have been given, there is no error, but merely an empty array being returned. From the evidence we are given, it appears that the query being executed by the OP's code is similar to the following (with the parameter value substituted manually): `SELECT last_ip FROM accounts WHERE login IN (' ''acb'' , ''gfh'' ');`

Answer (score 2):

Add a separate bound parameter for each value to be used in the *IN ()* condition. That way, the comma separating the values is not part of the values, and there will be no quotes escaped. If you need to get the values from an array, you can iterate over the array, calling [*bindValue()*](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) for each value.

```
$sql = " 
    SELECT last_ip
    FROM accounts 
    WHERE login IN (:login1, :login2) 
";
$pdo = $this->em->getConnection();
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':login1',"acb");         
$stmt->bindValue(':login2',"gfh");         
$stmt->execute();               
$rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $rs;
```

**Edit:**

Per the comment about an unknown number of values, as I alluded to in my explanation above, one should be able to loop through values ( presuming they are in an array), and use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to add the parameter names to the query text, like the example below (one could also use [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map) with a callback that *uses* `$stmt` to call `$stmt->bindValue()` and returns the strings):

```
$pdo = $this->em->getConnection();
$parameterNames = array();
foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    $parameterNames[] = ':login'.$index;
}
$sql = " 
SELECT last_ip
FROM accounts 
WHERE login IN (".implode(', ', $parameterNames).") ";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':login'.$index, $value);
}
```

Comment: But it is not convenient, especially in case when we don't know count of logins...

Comment: ಠ_ಠ What is `$xxxx` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DQL:

```
$logins = ['acb', 'gfh'];
$dql = " 
        SELECT a.last_ip
        FROM Accounts a
        WHERE a.login IN (?1)
";
$q = $this->em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter(1, $logins);
$result = $q->execute();
```

Comment: dontrince  dosen't want use use $login in sql